# OpenCV HoughCircles not working after using floodFill

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform, flood-fill

I am using HoughCircles and works great with a grayscale image, tried using a binary and still works as intended. After I use a floodFill to only detect the inner circle of my image the HoughCircles return an empty array. Here I have the code working:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 

# Read image. 
img = cv2.imread('terminales.webp', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 

# Convert to grayscale. 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

# Blur using 3 * 3 kernel. 
gray_blurred = cv2.blur(gray, (3, 3))
ret,binary_img = cv2.threshold(gray_blurred,220,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Copy the thresholded image.
im_floodfill = binary_img.copy()

# Mask used to flood filling.
# Notice the size needs to be 2 pixels than the image.
h, w = binary_img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)

# Floodfill from point (0, 0)
cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0,0), 255);

# Invert floodfilled image
im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)

# Combine the two images to get the foreground.
im_out = binary_img | im_floodfill_inv


# Apply Hough transform on the blurred image. 
detected_circles = cv2.HoughCircles(binary_img,  
                   cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 1, param1 = 50, 
               param2 = 30, minRadius = 10, maxRadius = 150) 

# Draw circles that are detected. 
if detected_circles is not None: 

    # Convert the circle parameters a, b and r to integers. 
    detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(detected_circles))

    for pt in detected_circles[0, :]: 
        a, b, r = pt[0], pt[1], pt[2] 

        # Draw the circumference of the circle. 
        cv2.circle(img, (a, b), r, (0, 255, 0), 2) 

        # Draw a small circle (of radius 1) to show the center. 
        cv2.circle(img, (a, b), 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
else:
    print("Nothing detected")

cv2.imshow("Detected Circle", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If I use "im_floodfill", "im_out" or "im_floodfill_inv" in HoughCircle instead of "binary_img" I don't get any results.
I don't know if I am missing something that can't be done.

[image: Image to be detected]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to detect something reducing parameter 2 and increasing minDist.

```
detected_circles_inner = cv2.HoughCircles(im_floodfill,  
                   cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 30, param1 = 50, 
               param2 = 15, minRadius = 10, maxRadius = 150)
```